# OR Operator in Google Sheets Not Working?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

This is the formula I am working on right now:

```
=FILTER(Data!A:K, SEARCH("Gretsch", Data!F:F)+SEARCH("Krutz", Data!F:F))
```

I'm trying to bring in both rows that include "Gretsch" and rows that include "Krutz". Just using one of those instead of both works just fine, and using keywords that the other has included in it's results (for example, searching just Gretsch brings up 10 or so (out of the 100+) products that include "Streamliner" in the F Column, as well as Gretsch, so using this formula:

```
=FILTER(Data!A:K, SEARCH("Gretsch", Data!F:F)+SEARCH("Streamliner", Data!F:F))
```

brings up the 10 or so products with both, but I'm looking for one OR the other, so why is that '+' acting like an AND operator instead? Am I just completely off base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEARCH` returns a number: the starting position where a string is found within another string. It's not a simple `1` like other tests for `TRUE`, and there is no `0` case (i.e., `FALSE`) as you have it written. In addition, if either `SEARCH` does not find the target string, it returns an error; and a number plus an error... returns an error (which is not `TRUE` and therefore will not be included in the `FILTER`).

A better approach to achieving `OR` with `FILTER`:

`=FILTER(Data!A:K, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Data!F:F),"gretsch|krutz"))`

The pipe symbol ("|") means `OR` in this context, and you may list as many pipe-separated strings as you like. Notice that the search range is wrapped in `LOWER` and that the terms to search are also lowercase; this assures the same kind of caps-agnostic search you were looking for with `SEARCH`.

By the way, based on your other recent post, you can also use `REGEXMATCH` with `NOT`, e.g.:

`=FILTER(Data!A:K, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Data!F:F),"gretsch|krutz"), NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Data!F:F),"case")))`

One additional note: Your post is tagged "Excel" and "Google Sheets." The formulas I've proposed will *only* work with Google Sheets. In most cases by far, it is best to tag a post here with *either* "Excel" *or* "Google Sheets" but not both, since the differences are substantial between the two.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Data!A:K, "where lower(F) contains 'gretsch' 
                     or lower(F) contains 'krutz'")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]